# How can i get jquery countdown to redirect to a reset file

Tags: javascript

here is my countdown

```
$('span.countdown').each(function() {
        var endtime = $(this).html();
        $(this).countdown({
            until:  endtime,
            format: 'dhmS',
            layout: '{d<}{dn} days {d>}{h<}{hn} hours {h>}{m<}{mn} mins {m>}{sn} secs',
            expiryUrl: self.location.href
        });
    });
}
```

i would like to redirect to index.php when countdown hits zero
:)

Answer (score 1):

```
            expiryUrl: self.location.href
    to

            expiryUrl: window.location.href

or 

            expiryUrl: "absolute url" //ie http://domain/index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to `expiryUrl: "something"`.

Comment: i have tried both with no results,i am atempting to redirect to my reset db php file at the end of that it redirects to index.php

Comment: $('span.countdown').each(function() {
  var endtime = $(this).html();
  $(this).countdown({
   until:  endtime,
   format: 'dhmS',
   layout: '{d<}{dn} days {d>}{h<}{hn} hours {h>}{m<}{mn} mins {m>}{sn} secs',
   expiryUrl: "http://www.elitepimps.info/something.php" 
  });
 });
}